# Bitbucket error when testing connection: “javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem”

Tags: java, ssl, continuous-integration, bitbucket, openshift

We are getting the following SSL error message when trying to test (ping) an outgoing SSL connection from Bitbucket (using webform) to any of the several Openshift masters in three separate clusters (otherwise working endpoints with webhooks that should be triggering builds upon every commit to a Bitbucket repo).

To reproduce, I simply create a test repo in Bitbucket and execute a SSL connection using Bitbucket's web interface, effectively trying to ping an existing endpoint (on-premise Openshift master to which we can otherwise connect from elsewhere) as follows:

```
Repository settings -> Webhooks -> Create webhook -> Name: "test" -> URL: https://my-openshift-url.com:my_port -> Test connection -> View details
```

The error message is (quite distinct from situations of bad URL or non-SSL protocols):

`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem`

I suspect it can be a certificate problem in Bitbucket, but Bitbucket admins have found no solution so far.

Comment: You need to add SSL key ignoring mechanism in your code. If possible, post more snippets of your code so that it will be easy to understand.

Comment: Thank you, I forwarde the hint to the repo admin. I would love to add snippets (more coder than clicker myself too:), but I have access to Bitbucket's webhooks configuration only via its web interface...

Comment: Any updates on this issue? I ran into it myself while linking the WebHook to Jenkins and can't figure out a solution. The issue appeared when I moved my Jenkins Server from HTTP to HTTPS

Answer (score 1):

hmm..., i heard of a similar problem.
you could try to add the certificates of the Openshift Masters to the 
bitbucket server's JDK CA keystore.